# Set Dynamic Base Url with Condition in Config Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to set a dynamic base URL in Codeigniter due to few following reasons.

- If IP using 10.3.1.77 change into **HTTPS**:

  ```
  $config['base_url'] = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
  str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
  ```
- Else, change into **HTTP**:

  ```
  $config['base_url'] = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
  str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
  ```

But I have no idea how to identify the IP.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple logic in config.php, remember application/config/config.php is a php script you can add any type of logic there!
try this out, edit the following code as per need.

```
 $config['base_url'] = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 10.3.1.77 ? 'https' : 'http'). "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```